# Is it necessary to replace setActiveCell with getActiveCell or setActiveRange?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying the new IDE that Google Apps Script provided and it seems the new editor marked one of my scripts as an error that needs fixing (in a form of suggestion).

[image: these are the suggestions]

My question is, is it necessary to replace `spreadsheet.setActiveCell()` with `spreadsheet.setActiveRange()` or `spreadsheet.getActiveRange()` ?

Did Google remove this command specifically? Because I couldn't find `setActiveCell()` on the Apps Script Reference anymore and it didn't appear as fill-in options when writing within the editor (even when I'm reverting to the legacy one).

Note that the script works fine as it is supposed to.

Comment: Hi there @dDennis ! At the end of your question I see «*Note that the script works fine as it is supposed to*», then I understand that your don't need code help and your question is only about the benefits of alternatives. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi @Jacques-GuzelHeron . That and I also want to double check whether `setActiveCell()` will be removed in the future (hence I need to get used with the alternatives) or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your new comment I understand that you want to know if `.setActiveCell()` would be removed and some alternatives if it does. As far as I can tell, there are no references to that method in the docs, so I strongly recommend you to get used to the alternatives. Some options are [`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange), [`SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setactiverangerange), [`Spreadsheet.getCurrentCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getcurrentcell) or [`Spreadsheet.setCurrentCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setcurrentcellcell). Please let me know if those choices are not enough in your implementation.

Comment: Exactly. I'm getting used with `Spreadsheet.setCurrentCell()` right now and thanks for clarifying. 

But still, I'm curious how the method `.setActiveCell()` written within my script still works (as I'm not the original owner of the code, I didn't know whether if such method exist in the legacy version or not).

For example, this code `spreadsheet.setActiveCell(CurrentCell.offset(5, 0))` results in **moving my Active Cell 5 rows lower from my Current Cell**. And without it, my code wouldn't resulted in the same way (my active cell won't move).